# Simple Postgresql Statement - column name does not exists

Tags: php, postgresql, string-constant

I've been pulling my hair out. I have a very simple postgre database, one specific table has a column named lName (uppercase N). Now I know with postgre I must quote lName since it contains an uppercase N.

I am trying to query the database with the following statement:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE "lName" LIKE "Smith"
```

But I am receive this error:

> Warning: pg_query()
>   [function.pg-query]: Query failed:
>   ERROR: column "Smith" does not exist
>   in .....

What is the issue here? Why is it saying the column is "Smith"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would guess:

```
 SELECT * FROM employee WHERE "lName" LIKE 'Smith'
```

(note the different quotes; `"foo"` is a quoted identifier; `'foo'` is a string literal)

Also, in most SQL dialects, a `LIKE` without a wildcard is equivalent to `=`; did you mean to include a wildcard?

Answer (score 5):

Because `"Smith"` is an identifier, and in that position, an identifier is expected to be a column.  What you probably meant is a string literal, which uses single quotes: `'Smith'`.  So

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE "lName" LIKE 'Smith'
```

You probably also want a wildcard in the string to search for (`'Smith%'`?).  `LIKE` matching is anchored to the beginning and end of a string, unlike typical regular expression matching.